# facebook connect still works with release-hashvalue, while the hashvalue on facebook is still the debug-hashvalue

Tags: android, eclipse, hash, publish, signing

So I have some kind of strange behaviour.

I was developing an app which allows the user to post images to facebook, everything worked fine in the debug stage.

I setup the app on facebook and used the app-id in my app, then I used the debug hashkey and entered into facebook. Everything worked fine like I said and i was able to post an image.

However when I signed my app with the key, which I intend to used for publishing, the app still worked and I was able to post images on facebook. This should have not been possible, since the hashkey in facebook was still the old debug key while my app already used the releasekey. (I used the default eclipse way for publish and creating the key, which is: Export -> then created a new Key and used it to sign the app)

The releasekey seems to be fine as I checked it with the keytool and it showed the correct keyalias and only reacted to the correct password.

So I went a head and entered the releasekeys hashvalue into facebook, then I used the debugkey on my app again and tried to post an image....it still worked which again should not be possible and I have now idea why.

My last resort was to try and create a new facebook app on one of my friends accounts. I took his app-id and used the releasehashkey for his facebook app. I was not able to post an image on facebook anymore since the annoying "an error occured please try again later" error occured.

So I would be very grateful if someone could enlighten me about what the hell is going on here and if I am doing anything wrong, since theroretically everything should work as expected.

P.S: I installed the release ready app on my device by putting the signed .apk file on the devices storage and then installed it from there. Where for the debug version I used eclipse run configuration.

EDIT:
So okay I did another approach to confirm my assumption, I did the following

I deleted the debug key on my PC and thus forced eclipse to create a new one, I checked the debug key with the keytool and the hash was in fact different.

So I deleted the app on my device and run the app from eclipse thus installing it on my device signed with the new debug key.

I tried posting on facebook again which as this point should be IMPOSSIBLE since the debug key is different. However I was stunned as it was still possible to post images....

My Assumption now is that the hash key does not mean anything to facebook at all and that the app is actually bounds to the app-id that is first used when using the facebook connect. This information seems to be stored somewhere on facebook.

However this is just a wild guess of mine, so again if anyone had the same problem and found an answer or has any intel on the topic I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I am either stupid or blind....or both, anyway the error was that the app which is tested it with had its sandbox mode set to disabled thus anyone using the app with a facebook account could post stuff. While the new app of my friends had its sandbox mode set to enanbled, thus only he was able to post stuff.                                                                                                                                  anyway this post helped me realising my mistake  [Android Facebook SDK - Failed to receive access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818691/android-facebook-sdk-failed-to-receive-access-token)